# Standardizing dependent variable to model random intercept and slope

Tags: regression, standardization

I have a model for a small data set (30 participants) where I would like to specify random intercepts for participants and a random slope for their ages, but don't have enough observations per participant. The DV is strongly left skewed (likely due to an interaction term containing many 0s). However, if I standardize the DV it works. Is standardizing the DV an acceptable practice in this context?

Comment: Welcome, banible :-). Maybe you can give us a little bit more detail: how many independent variables are in your model? How do you standardize your dependent variable? With the mean and sd of all observations considered as one sample? Roughly how many observations per person?

Comment: To add to Ute's questions, can you clarify how do you want to model the random slope? Is age the predictor and you want age's random slope for each participant, or do you want the random slope of some other predictor for each age levels?